# Transparent tooltip and modals on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native

I am trying to build tooltip and modals for an iOS app using react-native. Issue I am facing is that background of tooltips and modals is not transparent. However its showing fine on android version of the app.

Is there some setting I am missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have used different libraries like react-native-elements(tooltip, overlay), react-native date-time-picker and other dropdown and picker libraries of react-native but all are having black(solid color background) and actual layout is not being displayed.

Pasting a sample tooltip code as well,

```
<Tooltip withOverlay={true} overlayColor={Colors.unselected} backgroundColor={Colors.grey} width={250} height={'auto'}

  ModalComponent={Modal}

  popover={<EditMenu />}>

    <Icon name={'downcircle'} family={'ant'} color={Colors.grey} size={18} />

</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed when I updated xcode and used iOS 13. Previously I was using iOS 12. Also tested it on physical device and there modals and tooltips are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using RGBA background color with a fractional alpha channel value:

```js
<Tooltip backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)" />
```

Comment: I previously tried "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" but didn't work. Let me try 0.1 opacity as well.